# MongoDB nested lookup with 3 child levels

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to retrieve the entire single object hierarchy from the database as a JSON. 
I'm trying aggregate for hours and can't solve how to do it with my data. So I have three collections:

**form**

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "My first form" }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Second one" }
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "Another" }
```

**question**

```
{ "_id" : "q1", "form" : "1", "title": "What's your country?"}
{ "_id" : "q2", "form" : "1", "title": "What your favorite color?"}
{ "_id" : "q3", "form" : "1", "title": "Where do you live?"}
{ "_id" : "q4", "form" : "2", "title": "Where to go?"}
```

**option**

```
{ "_id" : "o1", "question" : "q1", "text" : "Brazil" }
{ "_id" : "o2", "question" : "q1", "text" : "EUA" }
{ "_id" : "o3", "question" : "q1", "text" : "China" }
{ "_id" : "o4", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Red" }
{ "_id" : "o5", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Blue" }
{ "_id" : "o6", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Green" }
```

I need to retrieve each form with all corresponding questions, and in each question the options for it. Like this:

```
[
   {
      _id:"q1",
      name: "My first form",
      questions: [
          { "_id" : "q1",
            "form" : "1", 
            "title": "What's your country?",
            "options": [
                  { "_id" : "o1", "question" : "q1", "text" : "Brazil" }
                  { "_id" : "o2", "question" : "q1", "text" : "EUA" },
                  { "_id" : "o3", "question" : "q1", "text" : "China" }
            ]
          },
          { "_id" : "q2",
            "form" : "1", 
            "title": "What your favorite color",
            "options": [
                  { "_id" : "o4", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Red" }
                  { "_id" : "o5", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Blue" },
                  { "_id" : "o6", "question" : "q2", "text" : "Green" }
            ]
          },
          { "_id" : "q3", 
            "form" : "1", 
            "title": "Where do you live?",
            "options": []
          }
      ]
   },
   ...
]
```

I've tried a lot of $lookup, $unwind, another $lookup and $project, but nothing give-me that result (forms with questions inside, questions with options inside).

Please, help me! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the around is querying the `question` collection, looking up their `question`s and grouping by `form`, and finally lookup form and project, in that order.

This should do it. Keep in mind that `_id` in the output of this aggregate is the form `_id`.

```
db.question.aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'option',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'question',
        as: 'options'
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$form",
        questions: {$push: {
            title: "$title",
            options: "$options",
            form: "$form"
        }}
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'form',
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: 'form'
    }},
    {$project: {
        name: {$arrayElemAt: ["$form.name", 0]},
        questions: true
    }}
]);
```

Actually.. this seems like a better alternative. It will return `form`s with no `question`s too.

```
db.form.aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'question',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'form',
        as: 'questions'
    }},
    {$unwind: {
        path: "$questions",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'option',
        localField: 'questions._id',
        foreignField: 'question',
        as: 'options'
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: {$first: "$name"},
        question: {$push: {
            title: "$questions.title",
            form: "$questions.form",
            options: "$options"
        }}
    }}
])
```

Comment: How is it not working for you? I made a few tweaks to it just mins ago.

Comment: I got your last edit. I saw it. The structure of you result, are right. But it don't got data. Take a look at the results here: https://pastebin.com/qddteCTq

Comment: I can see an issue with it, and that it is that if the form has no questions it won't be in the results, but I created the collections you gave as example, and I got this result: https://pastebin.com/0DqFq8LS

Comment: Sorry! It work! I just miss that you are querying "questions" collection. It work fine. Thanks! You save my day.

Comment: Remember that it won't return forms with no questions. I don't know if that's an issue though.

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa check the updated answer, that second aggregate seems like a much better alternative

Comment: it work well to! Thanks! Now, I must study more to understand how it really works. Great job! :)